# MySQL joint tables SUM and extra clause

Tags: mysql

I'm currently using 3 tables where I grab the number of users which got pending jobs with the following code:

```
SELECT count(u.user_id) AS nb_users
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT sj.jobs_userid AS unfinished_user
  FROM Scheduled_Jobs sj
  LEFT JOIN Last_Update lu
    ON lu.update_jobsid = sj.jobs_id
  WHERE sj.status = 1
  AND sj.date <= CURDATE()
  AND lu.update_id IS NULL
) AS uj -- unfinished jobs
  ON u.user_id = uj.unfinished_user
WHERE u.status = 1
AND uj.unfinished_user IS NULL
```

And here is a table example:

```
Users (user_id | email | password | status)
1 | user@asd.com  | xxx | 1
2 | user2@asd.com | xxx | 1
3 | user3@asd.com | xxx | 2
4 | user4@asd.com | xxx | 1
5 | user3@asd.com | xxx | 1

Scheduled_Jobs (job_id | user_id | date | points | status)
1  | 1 | 05/09/2019 | 5 | 1
2  | 1 | 05/10/2019 | 3 | 1
3  | 1 | 05/11/2019 | 6 | 1
4  | 1 | 05/12/2019 | 2 | 1
5  | 2 | 07/10/2019 | 7 | 1
6  | 2 | 07/11/2019 | 5 | 1
7  | 2 | 07/12/2019 | 3 | 1
8  | 3 | 10/10/2019 | 4 | 2
9  | 4 | 13/10/2019 | 1 | 1
10 | 4 | 13/11/2019 | 6 | 1
11 | 5 | 15/10/2019 | 5 | 1
12 | 5 | 15/11/2019 | 4 | 1
13 | 5 | 15/12/2019 | 5 | 1

Last_Update (update_id | job_id | status)
1 | 1  | 1
2 | 2  | 1
3 | 3  | 1
4 | 5  | 1
5 | 8  | 1
6 | 9  | 1
7 | 11 | 1
```

I've got 2 problems which doesn't seem to be able to fix them. I am trying to add an extra where clause update_status = 1 (seems to break the query..) and
I'm also trying to show the SUM of total points of the last job completed but I'm not sure how to achieve that.

So based on the example above we've got 4 active users with scheduled jobs. The result will be (for today) that 3 out of those 4 users (1,4,5 since user 2 missed jobid 6) have no pending jobs and their total points would be 12 (6+1+5).

Comment: you have not a column  update_status in your  schema  . .. explain better .

Comment: Last_Update table, status column is what I meant.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a left joined clause  you should add  condtion related  to left join table in the related  ON clause  using AND

```
  SELECT sj.jobs_userid AS unfinished_user
  FROM Scheduled_Jobs sj
  LEFT JOIN Last_Update lu
    ON lu.update_jobsid = sj.jobs_id
      AND lu.status =1 
  WHERE sj.status = 1
  AND sj.date <= CURDATE()
  AND lu.update_id IS NULL
```

if you for this use the where clause  then this work as an inner join ..